# Extracting coordinates of region within matrix

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 3D matrix, within which I have identified a "region of interest" - a bounding box - which I would like the indices for.

I have the upper and lower bound limits of each axis:

```
([x:13  y:5 z:21] [x:27 y:29 z:35])
```

But I am not quite sure how to get all of the indices for values inside this box. I believe the "order" I have currently using for these is C conventional which I should keep.

Is there a simple way to do this using python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find the indices of an array fulfilling a condition. `numpy.where` returns a tuple, the first element contains the indices.

#### Example

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(0, 100, 10) # 0, 10, 20, ...
ind = numpy.where(a>30)[0]
print(ind) # [4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing:

```
my3d[13:28, 5:30, 21:36]
```

Note that the upper bounds are exclusive so might want to increment them by one.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to get the indices however of all the values in this range. Sorry if the question wasnt clear!

Comment: Can you shown an example of your desired output. Do you just want a list of `(x, y, z)` tuples like `[(13, 5, 21), (14, 5, 22) ... (28, 30, 36)]`?

Comment: I have found a solution :), my desired output was - ([13, 13,13....27,27,27], [5,5,5,..., 30, 30, 30], [21, 22, 23,..,34,35,36]) - if that makes sense? In the end I just added the lower bound to the indices of my extracted box. Not pretty but it works! Thanks for your help Mike